# Ubuntu server/Debian/CentOS randomly halts while booting

Tags: debian, ubuntu, centos

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2950 (Dual Intel Xeons 
@ 2.5GHz, 32GB DDR2, An old 80GB SATA3 drive [RAID controller died]) and it randomly halts while booting, I'm using Ubuntu server which seems to show more progress during startup, however the same issue happens with CentOS and Debian. I ran both CPUs at full load for 5 minutes and seen no random halting or any issues (albeit it got quite warm), as well as running an extensive memory test which was successful. The recovery mode version of the kernel does work, and it allows me to drop to a root shell etc.

Ubuntu server (16.04) loads the kernel and even starts starting services, and then just halts for no reason.

Debian dosen't even start to load services, etc. when booting just says /dev/sda is clean and halts, even lack of cursor blink.

CentOS installer don't work in general.

There are no error messages, it just does this randomly HOWEVER I was able  to get into debian and ubuntu's recovery mode.
The point of halting changes for every boot, also there are NO errors in console.

Link to /var/log/dpkg.log: https://pastebin.com/YUqVUp9m

Ling to /var/log/lastlog: It was empty

Link to /var/log/faillog: It was empty

Link to /var/log/bootstrap.log: https://pastebin.com/CmrHf2MY

Contents of /var/log/dmesg.log: `(Nothing has been logged yet.)`

When I refer to halt I mean a complete halt of the CPU's operations. ie. No input or output to console, serial port, etc. and even a lack of response to keyboard input such as Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C.

Also I ran the DELL diagnostics tool (Linux version wouldn't work but the MS-DOS version did) and it reported everything was fine

Comment: Could you please [update your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/452323/edit) with additional context. Include the relevant error messages or the messages displayed where it halts.

Comment: There are none, it just halts randomly and the messages change every time I boot. Tomorrow, Ill record a video of it booting but I currently can't since its at my workplace

Comment: What is the last thing you see on your screen? We can try to help you but it will be difficult to determine a solution without any information about what exact step halted or potentially failed. If you can access any logs please include the output of the following command `tail -n 100 /var/log/dmesg.log`

Comment: The point of halting changes for every boot, also there are NO errors in console

Comment: Please include the output of any relevant boot logs such as `dmesg.log` to assist others in discovering an acceptable answer to your question.

Comment: I currently cannot access them, but tomorrow I will put the logs on pastebin and give you a link

Comment: Random crashes, with no indicators of software faults, usually indicate dying hardware.

Comment: By "halt", do you mean power off, or something like a panic or kernel oops?

Comment: [Dell diagnostic tools](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln114988/dell-diagnostic-tools-to-diagnose-and-fix-hardware-problems-on-your-dell-pc-tablet-or-servers?lang=en)

Comment: Refer to edited post